# What is simpliest way to get Line number from char position in String?

Tags: c#, string

What is simpliest way to get Line number from char position in String in C#? 
(or get Position of line (first char in line) )
Is there any built-in function ? If there are no such function is it good solution to write extension like :

```
public static class StringExt {
    public static int LineFromPos(this String S, int Pos) { 
        int Res = 1;
        for (int i = 0; i <= Pos - 1; i++)
            if (S[i] == '\n') Res++;
        return Res;                
    }

    public static int PosFromLine(this String S, int Pos) { .... }

}
```

?

Edited: Added method PosFromLine

Comment: If you are calling this a lot, for example over many hundreds/thousands of lines, there are better ways than you are doing.  For example, if you're processing a file sequentially, you could 'remember' the line number you are on, and increment it every time you hit a newline.  Or you could 'cache' the line number for every 1000 characters or so with a dictionary, and use the cache entry preceding the query as a starting point.  If performance isn't an issue, go for something clear Jan/Jon's directly, though.

Comment: Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

A slight variation on Jan's suggestion, without creating a new string:

```
var lineNumber = input.Take(pos).Count(c => c == '\n') + 1;
```

Using [`Take`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb503062.aspx) limits the size of the input without having to copy the string data.

You should consider what you want the result to be if the given character *is* a line feed, by the way... as well as whether you want to handle `"foo\rbar\rbaz"` as three lines.

EDIT: To answer the new second part of the question, you could do something like:

```
var pos = input.Select((value, index) => new { value, index })
               .Where(pair => pair.value == '\n')
               .Select(pair => pair.index + 1)
               .Take(line - 1)
               .DefaultIfEmpty(1) // Handle line = 1
               .Last();
```

I *think* that will work... but I'm not sure I wouldn't just write out a non-LINQ approach...

Comment: +1: Not for "Skeet"-factor reasons ;-), but for the "without creating a new string"

Comment: @Jon: about "foo\rbar\rbaz" : I think for best result it should recognize all three kinds of line breaks ("\n", "\r", "\r\n"), but all solutions are interesting

Comment: @Astronavigator: That becomes harder, because you'd want to count "\r\n" as a single line break, so it becomes stateful. Ick. Unless you *need* that behaviour, I'd stick to counting `\n` :)

Comment: You could also just pre-process with `.Replace("\r\n", "\n").Replace("\r", "\n")` before the LINQ stage.

Answer (score 12):

Count the number of newlines in the substringed input string.

```
var lineNumber = input.Substring(0, pos).Count(c=>c == '\n') + 1;
```

*edit*: and do a `+1` because line numbers begin at 1 :-)

Comment: Very clear and obvious, while probably not as performant as the example in the question.

Comment: If you want to code something performant you might not even ask this question and always maintain the line number variable as you do your process

Answer (score 5):

If you are going to call the function many times on the same long string, this class can be usefull. It caches the new line positions, so that later it can perform O(log (line breaks in string)) lookup for `GetLine` and O(1) for `GetOffset`.

```
public class LineBreakCounter
{
    List<int> lineBreaks_ = new List<int>();
    int length_;

    public LineBreakCounter(string text)
    {
        if (text == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(text));

        length_ = text.Length;
        for (int i = 0; i < text.Length; i++)
        {
            if (text[i] == '\n')
                lineBreaks_.Add(i);

            else if (text[i] == '\r' && i < text.Length - 1 && text[i + 1] == '\n')
                lineBreaks_.Add(++i);
        }
    }

    public int GetLine(int offset)
    {
        if (offset < 0 || offset > length_)
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(offset));

        var result = lineBreaks_.BinarySearch(offset);
        if (result < 0)
            return ~result;
        else
            return result;
    }

    public int Lines => lineBreaks_.Count + 1;

    public int GetOffset(int line)
    {
        if (line < 0 || line >= Lines)
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(line));

        if (line == 0)
            return 0;

        return lineBreaks_[line - 1] + 1;
    }
}
```

Here is my test case:

```
[TestMethod]
public void LineBreakCounter_ShouldFindLineBreaks()
{
    var text = "Hello\nWorld!\r\n";
    var counter = new LineBreakCounter(text);

    Assert.AreEqual(0, counter.GetLine(0));
    Assert.AreEqual(0, counter.GetLine(3));
    Assert.AreEqual(0, counter.GetLine(5));
    Assert.AreEqual(1, counter.GetLine(6));
    Assert.AreEqual(1, counter.GetLine(8));
    Assert.AreEqual(1, counter.GetLine(12));
    Assert.AreEqual(1, counter.GetLine(13));
    Assert.AreEqual(2, counter.GetLine(14));

    Assert.AreEqual(3, counter.Lines);
    Assert.AreEqual(0, counter.GetOffset(0));
    Assert.AreEqual(6, counter.GetOffset(1));
    Assert.AreEqual(14, counter.GetOffset(2));
}
```

Answer (score -2):

For who is interested in javascript or a more iterative approach.

```
const {min} = Math

function lineAndColumnNumbersAt(str, pos) {
    let line = 1, col = 1
    const _pos = min(str.length, pos)
    for (let i = 0; i < _pos; i++)
        if (str[i] === '\n') {
            line++
            col = 1
        } else
            col++
    return {line, col}
}

lineAndColumnNumbersAt('test\ntest\ntest', 8)
```

Comment: The question is tagged with and asks for a solution in C#.

Comment: I know this but how hard is this to convert to C#?

Answer (score -2):

In ruby:

```rb
      def line_index
        source[0...position].count("\n")
      end

      def line_number
        line_index + 1
      end

      def lines
        source.lines
      end

      def line_source
        lines[line_index]
      end

      def line_position
        position - lines[0...line_index].map(&:size).sum
      end
```

Comment: This is not a Ruby question.  The question is tagged with and asks for a solution in C#.

Comment: @LanceU.Matthews Agreed, it's just that I ended up here when looking for how to find the line source and line position from byte position in a string (not specifying any language in Google) and I think the ruby solution is more readable so that could help others

Comment: I see that Ruby is at the top of [your Top Tags](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12544391/dorian?tab=tags) and C# is nowhere to be found.  _Of course_ a Ruby user is going to find Ruby more readable than C#.  A C# user is going to find C# code a lot more readable and useful, too, which is why posting a Ruby answer here is not useful.  Even if this were the right language, it's a code-only answer with no explanation of what it's doing, so not very good on that front, either.