# How do I find a line number by searching for a string in a text file

Tags: c#

I'm trying to find the line number of a string that I have searched for in a text file. The reason is so that I can add 1 to the number and then read that line. That means I can make the file easy to read without making thousands of lines of code to step through the file.

Comment: Side note: posting your effort on "thousands of lines of code" would make your question better... Also I have no idea how you can turn `File.ReadAllLines` I've suggested on your previous post into so many lines of code...

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(fileName))
    {
    string line = "";
        while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            if (line.IndexOf("YourString") >= 0)
            {    

            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this will do the job for you.  You need to get the index of the string that you have found.

[What is simpliest way to get Line number from char position in String?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7255743/c-what-is-simpliest-way-to-get-line-number-from-char-position-in-string)

There are lots of ways to get the index of what you want to find:

string.IndexOf - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.indexof(v=vs.110).aspx

Regex matches also give you an index.

So first you find the index of what you are searching for, then you use the link I posted at the top.

Comment: Answers should be more than simple links to other questions on StackOverflow, and if this question is sufficiently answered at that link, then the question should be closed as a duplicate.

Comment: updated my post to add more information