# Simple way to access the line number in a MatchEvaluator

Tags: c#, regex

I want to make a multi-line replacement which also depends on the line number of the match start.

I know I can access the character index and match length from the `Match` parameter in the `MatchEvaluator` but need a simple way to generate the line number from this information!

I cannot process the string line by line since the Regex will span multiple lines

The "target" will look something like this:

```
START_TOKEN

some content that will be dropped during replacement

END_TOKEN
```

and the replacement should look something like this:

```
START_TOKEN
  some static content 
  some content based on line number
END_TOKEN
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is:

```
MatchEvaluator me = (Match m)
{
  var lineNumber = theStringWhichIsWorkedUpon.Take(m.Index).Count(c => c == '\n') + 1;
  //...
};

var theStringWhichIsWorkedUpon = myRegex.Replace(theStringWhichIsWorkedUpon, me);
```

The answer is borrowed from https://stackoverflow.com/a/7255774/1254743